# DynamoDB scan function returns correct results, but with DynamoDBResponseError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to retrieve any 10 results from a table in my database using the scan function as follows:

```
  conn = boto.connect_dynamodb(
         aws_access_key_id=config.AWS_KEY,
         aws_secret_access_key=config.AWS_SECRET)

  table = conn.get_table('tablename')
  results = table.scan(attributes_to_get={'id'},
            max_results=10)

  for item in results:
    print item

  ./dbtest.py
   {'id': 'SkAJWDUZPSNrwepf7gdnFhExXPFABmqLjk1ADDRJuoo'}
   {'id': 'RjAVvd4SAmjtUbXEYmzBaIIDuruL5UZWEQPdcpj4XRc'}
   ...
```

But then I get this error at the end (after the correct results are returned):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mediatest.py", line 23, in <module>
    for item in results:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer2.py", line 767, in scan
    object_hook=item_object_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 521, in scan
    return self.make_request('Scan', json_input, object_hook=object_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 121, in make_request
    retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 746, in _mexe
    status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/dynamodb/layer1.py", line 148, in _retry_handler
    json_response)
boto.exception.DynamoDBResponseError: DynamoDBResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{'Message': 'Expected null', '__type': 'com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException'}
```

Am I not handling something that needs to be handled?

Comment: What is you boto version? (``boto.__version__``)

Comment: I'm running 2.5.2. I get this error even when I remove the attributes_to_get variable

Comment: What about ``db.layer1.region.name`` and ``db.layer1.Version``?

Comment: @jtlebi This error seems to occur when I'm requesting less items than the table has. So in this case I'm requesting 10 items from a table of 15 items. If I request all 15 items or more, I don't get the error. I'm unsure how to handle this

Comment: I think you should report a bug to the Boto team. I tried 10 elements on a table with 100+ and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake on the scan line:

```
results = table.scan(attributes_to_get={'id'},
        max_results=10)
```

instead of

```
results = table.scan(attributes_to_get=['id'],
        max_results=10)
```

EDIT:

This works with Boto 2.5.2

```
import boto

db = boto.connect_dynamodb()

table = db.get_table('MyTable')
res = table.scan(attributes_to_get=['id'], max_results=10)

for i in res:
    print i
```

Comment: When I make that change, I get a different error and no results: TypeError: set(['id']) is not JSON serializable

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere in the loop that displays the results. When I take that part out, I don't get an error anymore.

Comment: out of curiousity, how would I adjust your sample query to loop through 10 results at a time until there are no more results?

Comment: You would not use ``max_results=10`` but ``request_limit=10`` instead. This instructs DynamoDB to send results by pages of, at most, 10 results. Just loop over the results and Boto will do the magic for you.

For lower-level control, see layer1.scan instead.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using db.layer1.scan() instead of the layer2 function. Thank you for walking me through this. I've submitted a bug report.